# Do animals have the notion of fair share and fractions?

Tags: behaviour

There are already several experiments showing that animals (not only humans) can do some math: counting and problem solving.

My question is: what about the notion of fair share and fractions? I am looking for any reference or study!

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please take a [tour] and visit the [help] for more information on the Biology Stack. Please note the [homework](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) policy. So - what have you found in your searches, and what do you mean by "animals" - note that we are animals, as are insects, fish, birds, primates, other mammals...

Comment: please take a look here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=meiU6TxysCg